# How do I create a pattern string for the following regex in java?

Tags: java, regex, java-8, pattern-matching, java-7

I have a pattern that needs to be matched in a string and I'm unable to figure out the correct regex pattern.

A string may contain multiple matches of this pattern and I need the count of it.

1. Starts with lowercase english letter.
2. Zero or more occurances of any of these - lower english letters, digits and colons.
3. one Forward slash - /
4. Sequence of one or more lower case english letters and igits.
5. one Backslash - \
6. Sequence of one or more lower case english letters.

So far I've succeeded in writing this pattern as follows:

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String line=sc.nextLine();
    String patern="(([a-z]+)([a-z0-9:]*)(\\/)([a-z0-9]+)(\\)([a-z]+))";
    Pattern r=Pattern.compile(patern);
    Matcher m=r.matcher(line);
    int count=0;
    while(m.find()) {       
        count+=1;
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

But that's not giving me what I want. Any help from someone??

Comment: post your input string.

Comment: `(\\)` should be `(\\\\)`

Comment: could you edit the post to include few valid and invalid strings for the regex

Comment: Input string `w:/a\bc::/12\xyz` should give output - 8

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works for your requirements, but you added `\\` in `(\\/)` which you don't need.

You want the output to be 8, but there are 7 capturing group. You can get 8 if you also count the full match.

`(([a-z]+)([a-z0-9:]*)(/)([a-z0-9]+)(\\\\)([a-z]+))`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DWbdfl/1)

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/RXGN47121)

To get only the match without the grouping constructs you could use a more compact version and you might add anchors to match the start and the end of the string `^$`

[`^[a-z][a-z0-9:]*/[a-z0-9]+\\[a-z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/wRabMb/1)

In Java:

`^[a-z][a-z0-9:]*/[a-z0-9]+\\\\[a-z]+$`

Answer (score 0):

following might help:

```
^[a-z]+[a-z0-9:]*\/[a-z0-9]+\\[a-z]+
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
                String line=sc.nextLine();
                String patern="^[a-z][a-z0-9:]*\\/[a-z0-9]+\\\\[a-z]+$";
                Pattern r=Pattern.compile(patern);
                Matcher m=r.matcher(line);
                int count=0, i=0;
                while(line.length()>i) 
                {
                    int j=0;
                    while(line.substring(i).length()>j)
                    {
                        if(m.find())
                        {
                            count+=1;
                            //System.out.println("at i="+i+"wher count="+count);
                        }
                        j++;
                        m=r.matcher(line.substring(i).substring(0,j));
                    }

                    i++;
                    m=r.matcher(line.substring(i));

                }
                List<String> li=new ArrayList<>();
                System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: I've edited it. It should work. If not, tell me for what input it doesn't work.